# ODP.NET and SELECT INTO statement

Tags: c#, odp.net

Is there a way to implement a simple `SELECT INTO` statement like

```sql
SELECT First_Name 
INTO :Name 
FROM Employees 
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 2
```

with a return value parameter ("Name") using ODP.NET?

This is how I try to implement it, but the OracleCommand throw an 1006 exception: "ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist"

```
    public void getEmployee(int employee_id)
    {
        string cmdQuery = @"SELECT First_Name, Email, Salary INTO :FirstName, :EmailAddress, :CurrentSalary FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE employee_id = :Employee_id";
        trans_r = conn_r.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdQuery, conn_u);
            cmd.BindByName = true;

            //WHERE Parameters
            OracleParameter paramDepartment_Id = new OracleParameter("Employee_id", employee_id);
            paramDepartment_Id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDepartment_Id);

            //INTO Parameters
            OracleParameter param_Name_out = new OracleParameter("FirstName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param_Name_out);
            OracleParameter param_Email_out = new OracleParameter("EmailAddress", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param_Email_out);
            OracleParameter param_Salary_out = new OracleParameter("CurrentSalary", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param_Salary_out);

            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            OracleCommandBuilder cb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);

            cmd.ExecuteReader();

        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237622/odp-net-output-string-parameter-does-not-return-value) help?

Comment: So, you want in .Net application that uses ODP.NET get result of query in single variable?

Comment: @AlexejSommer, It can be single or multiple variables. The question is if there is a way to get those vars using a Return value OracleParameter.

I just added an example of my code

Comment: Caution, you used the name paramDepartment_Id for the Employee id. If this isn't the real code you are using make sure you haven't accidentally used the wrong parameter.

Comment: Also, try using ParameterDirection.Output rather than ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SELECT INTO" is actually part of PL/SQL language, not SQL. So you need to use an anonymous PL/SQL block (wrap it in BEGIN and END)

Example code:
http://oradim.blogspot.com/2007/04/odpnet-tip-anonymous-plsql-and.html

Also, try using ParameterDirection.Output rather than ParameterDirection.ReturnValue

Answer (score 0):

Anytime ODP.net throws a param not found error, usually means the param names don't match, the number of params aren't correct, or the params are improperly formatted. The parameters must be ":PARAM" in the param config being prefixed with ":"

```
 public void getEmployee(int employee_id)
{
    string cmdQuery = @"SELECT First_Name, Email, Salary INTO :FirstName, :EmailAddress, :CurrentSalary FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE employee_id = :Employee_id";
    trans_r = conn_r.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdQuery, conn_u);
        cmd.BindByName = true;

        //WHERE Parameters
        OracleParameter paramDepartment_Id = new OracleParameter(":Employee_id", employee_id);
        paramDepartment_Id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDepartment_Id);

        //INTO Parameters
        OracleParameter param_Name_out = new OracleParameter(":FirstName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param_Name_out);
        OracleParameter param_Email_out = new OracleParameter(":EmailAddress", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param_Email_out);
        OracleParameter param_Salary_out = new OracleParameter(":CurrentSalary", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param_Salary_out);

        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        OracleCommandBuilder cb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);

        cmd.ExecuteReader();

    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try arranging the params to be in order as the query has them. I've had problems with certain configs where it doesn't actually look at the name, but rather the order they appear in the query. Also, here's an example I found that may give you a different way to do what you are trying to do: [link](http://oradim.blogspot.com/2007/04/odpnet-tip-anonymous-plsql-and.html)